# Canvas - fill multiple images with texture/pattern

Tags: javascript, canvas

my question is exact like this
[Fill image with texture/pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28545747/fill-image-with-texture-pattern)
but I want to fill multiple objects in a canvas with different texture/pattern.

in the above question I want to draw two images of the sofa and fill them  with different texture/pattern.

Comment: What have you tried? Wouldn't you just do it twice with different textures?

Comment: I have tried but it's not working. one object is disappearing.

Comment: There are no objects on a canvas, just pixels.

Comment: @pawel thanks for explanation. I just want to draw two image on a canvas and fill them with different pattern.

Comment: You could use a temporary canvas to fill the first image with a pattern, put the result on the target canvas, then use the temporary canvas to fill another image with another pattern and add the result to the target canvas.

Comment: can you add a demo on plunker?

Comment: @pawel has the right idea. Just create that second canvas in-memory with `var tempCanvas = document.createElement('canvas')`